# How to use vue2.leaflet.markercluster in Nuxt.js project?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to use [vue2.leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/jperelli/vue2-leaflet-markercluster) in a nuxt project but when using the component in the console it gives the error

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

My code:

```
<template>
  <div id="map" style="height: 100vh">
    <client-only>
      <l-map>
        <l-tile-layer></l-tile-layer>
        <v-marker-cluster>
    <v-marker v-for="c in elements" v-if="c.id !== null" :lat-lng="c.latlon">
      <v-popup :content="c.tooltipContent"></v-popup>
    </v-marker>
  </v-marker-cluster>
      </l-map>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from "vue2-leaflet-markercluster"
export default {
"elements": [{/*elements*/}]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Add [vue2-leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/) or [nuxt-leaflet](https://github.com/schlunsen/nuxt-leaflet)
2. install vue2-leaflet-markercluster.

   ```
    npm install --save vue2-leaflet-markercluster
   ```
3. Create a file named **vue2-leaflet-markercluster.js** in plugins folder with the following content.

   ```
   import Vue from "vue";
   import * as L from "leaflet";
   import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from "vue2-leaflet-markercluster";
   import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
   import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css";
   import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css";

   Vue.component("v-marker-cluster", Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster);

    const LeafletPlugin = {
     install(Vue) {
      Vue.prototype.$L = L;
     }
    };

   Vue.use(LeafletPlugin);
   ```
4. In your **nuxt.config.js** file add the following object into plugins array

   ```
   {src: '~/plugins/vue2-leaflet-markercluster.js', mode:'client'},
   ```
5. In your html/component use v-marker cluster as

   ```
    <div id="map-wrap" style="height: 100vh">
     <client-only>
      <l-map :zoom=13 :center="[55.9464418,8.1277591]">
       <l-tile-layer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></l-tile-layer>
      <v-marker-cluster>
       <l-marker :lat-lng="[55.9464418,7.1277591]"></l-marker>
       <l-marker :lat-lng="[55.9464418,8.1277591]"></l-marker>
       <l-marker :lat-lng="[55.9464418,9.1277591]"></l-marker>
      </v-marker-cluster>
      </l-map>
     </client-only>
    </div>
   ```